# Call from Javascript to Controller Action and from this refresh site

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a small SVG Editor, where I could delete Objects.
These Objects are loaded from database and some of them belong to eachother.
Now if I want to delete one of such a "Group" of objects, I could remove it in the database, using a Controller Action and also delete the graphic out of the svg.
But If I want to delete the whole Group, I'd like to delete the objects in the database, by using an Action and I'd like to reload the whole page, for not searching all Elements and deleting them manually.

So the easiest way would be to invoke the Index-Action after deleting the records.
Is that possible?
How would you call the Removing Action and then the Index-Action, out of javascript?

```js
public ActionResult Index(int Id = 0, string PageNumber = "1")
{
    ///do a lot of stuff
}

public ActionResult DeleteSubFunction(int id, int projectId, string pageNumber)
{
    if (id == 0)
        return null;
    SymbolDataProvider.DeleteSubFunction(id, User.Identity.Name); //delete the recordsets
    return Index(projectId, pageNumber);
}
```

Calling this like

```js
function removeSubFunction(id) {
    if (confirm('Möchten Sie die Unterfunktion unwiederruflich löschen?')) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: appBaseUrl + 'Symbols/DeleteSubFunction',
            data: {
                id: id,
                projectId: projectId,
                pageNumber: pageNumber
            }
        });
    }
}
```

...throws a Http500 Error.

Is it worth to try on or isn't that possible?

Comment: Have your tried without `symbol` word `appBaseUrl + '/DeleteSubFunction'`

Comment: What value holds that `appBaseUrl`? And I believe you should refresh the page inside the `success` callback available in the `ajax()` settings.

Comment: appBaseUrl contains "@Url.Content("~")" and is needed because the scripts are in an external file. 
Can you give me an example to refresh in the success-result?